# What does "Combat bundled in cliché" mean?

Tags: phrase-meaning

There was the following sentence in Time magazine’s (November 18) article titled, “Chris Christie Was Born to Run”:

> Behind closed doors at a Westin hotel in Boston, where the governor
>   laid out his not so  veiled pitch for the party's 2016 nomination.
>   "I'm in this business to  win," he told the crowd of Republican
>   leaders.
>
> It was pure Christie, **combat bundled in cliché.** Ever since he ousted
>   Democratic incumbent Jon Corzine in 2009, he has run the Garden State
>   with combustible passion, blunt talk and the kind of bipartisan
>   dealmaking  that no one seems to do anymore.

http://content.time.com/time/magazine/article/0,9171,2156871,00.html#ixzz2k2blMOs4

I don’t get the idea of the word, “combat bundled in cliché.” What does it mean?

Does it mean Chris Christie was born to combat? Is “combat bundled” a cliché?

Comment: It is explained: "combustible passion, blunt talk and the kind of bipartisan dealmaking"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means he has a combative personality – at least politically – yet his political rhetoric is heavily steeped with cliché (as politicians are wont to do – along with political columnists as well).

I'm having trouble trying to figure out if the writer is admiring Christie, or making disparaging remarks. I would interpret "combat bundled in cliché" to mean "all boisterous  bluster, but no substance" (or, as the idiom goes, *[all bark and no bite](http://www.usingenglish.com/reference/idioms/all+bark+and+no+bite.html)*). Yet I would regard "the kind of bipartisan dealmaking that no one seems to do anymore" as complimentary, especially in this era of U.S. politics (on the heels of a government shutdown and summer sequester).

In any case, it's **not** an established expression – I've never heard it before, and a Google search only returned 5 hits – one to your question, and four more to the *Time* piece.